# DATEDIFF/Case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Please see the below query (This is part of a longer code that I need to edit)

```
select 'Admit '+cast **(DATEDIFF(day,(case when Sc.AppointmentDateTime is null then Ws.EndTime else Sc.AppointmentDateTime end),sp.AdmissionDateTime) as varchar)+' day(s) later; ' AS 'data()'**
from WHREPORTING.APC.Spell sp
where sp.AdmissionDate>='01 jan 2016'
```

Now I believe the part in bold brings out the `DATEDIFF` of the 2 dates as a figure. The output looks like this..

**"Admit 1 day(s) later; "**

What I am trying to do is somehow make the output specify whether it is 1-2 days later, or 2-14 days later. if that makes sense? So if the figure is 5 it would say "Admit 2-14 days later"

Would I need another case statement nested in there somehow?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Use: select CONCAT( 'damit **',  DATEDIFF...)

Comment: Not too sure how I would use CONCAT to do this? (Sorry i am relatively new to SQL..)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. with **CONCAT()** you can add some strings to one and in your sample it is 'Admit ** ' + (result of DATEDIFF(...) + ' day(s) later; ' AS 'data()'

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT (
    'Admit ** '
    , DATEDIFF(DAY,(CASE WHEN Sc.AppointmentDateTime IS NULL THEN Ws.EndTime ELSE Sc.AppointmentDateTime END)) 
    , ' day(s) later; ' AS 'data()'
  ) AS `data`
    FROM WHREPORTING.APC.Spell sp
WHERE sp.AdmissionDate>='01 jan 2016';
```